# Can't change Hyper Terminal Hardware Settings

Tags: windows, terminal

Anyone here any good with Hyperterminal?  Am having a nightmare trying to use it at work to update our telephone extensions.  The company who supply our PABX box have told me that XP does strange things to Hyperterminal and that I should use Win2k.  Which I did with the same result.

I have narrowed the problem dowwn to the Hardware Settings for the connection in Hyper Terminal.  No matter what I set (and I need 7E1) it defaults back to 8N1.  Has anyone seen this behaviour before and know of a simple way around it?  (Apart from buying a more expensive commercial version of Hyper Terminal, as suggested by our support people).

Edit: I should point out I have to connect via a phone line so a direct serial connection is not an option.

Cheers

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end ditched XP and Hyper Terminal completely.  We use Wyse boxes at our company so was able to set one of those up to dial the correct extension and use an interactive terminal session while also giving me correct control of the Parity and Stop Bits etc.  Worked like a charm and means we no longer have to have a separate Laptop to perform this function.

Cheers for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try at [ZOC Terminal](http://wwww.emtec.com/zoc/) too.  It's commercial, but I found it the most user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TeraTerm](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/), a freeware terminal emulator. Much better then hyperterm.

Answer (score 0):

Putty also does terminal emulation -- start it, and select the "Serial" radio button. Then enter your COM-port and voila!

Comment: Either of these able to dial a phone number to open the terminal session?  Have no access to a serial port on the PABX box so have to dial a local extension when in the office or corresponding telephone number when at home (as now, hate taking work home lol)